# AIR: NativeWindow startMove only vertical?

Tags: adobe, air

is it possible to use the startMove Method in AS3 and limit the movement only to the y-axis?
I want my window only to be dragable vertically.

Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, given that the actual movement of the window is done by the operating system alone (and I can't think of any application right now that restricts such a movement).

But maybe you can emulate such behaviour by encapsulating your actual application into a different window. You could then change the actual application size to the full screen and make it transparent and use [`startDrag`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) to emulate the dragging of the inner window. Because with that function you can specify boundaries in which the movement is allowed.
I don't know if that will work as you would like it to, however.